# How do you keep the footer at the bottom of the screen even when you decrease the width of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I am currently setting the footer for copyright information.

```
footer {
    display:block; 
    position: fixed; 
    width:100%; 
    top:calc(100vh - 30%); 
    font-family: "Avenir Lt Std", Arial; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding:2px;
    z-index:0; 
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

Thanks to others on the site, `top:cal(100vh - 30%)` keeps the footer at the bottom of the page when the browser is at maximum width.  As soon as you decrease the width of the browser, the footer floats upward. Is there a way to keep it on the bottom no matter the dimensions of the browser?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
footer
{
display: block;
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
colour: white;
font-size: 12px;
opacity: 0.5;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it!